# Find parametric equations for the arc of a circle of radius $6$ from $P=(0,0)$ to $Q=(12,0)$

Tags: calculus, parametric

## My Dilemma

I'm having trouble finding out the first step to this problem.

So far all I have is:

$$
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= 6\cos(t) + 6\\
y(t) &= 6\sin(t)
\end{align*}
$$

## The Question

Find parametric equations for the arc of a circle of radius $6$ from $P=(0,0)$ to $Q=(12,0)$.

$$
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \text{___}\\
y(t) &= \text{___}\\
\text{___}\ <  \ &t < \text{___}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: What you have looks right for the first part.

As far as t,

$0<t<2\pi$ works, but if you want the smallest answer possible, $0<t<3\pi/2$ works. Think of the range of values of $t$ needed to cover the interval $[-1,1]$ for sine and cosine and this should follow.

Comment: Well, you already wrote down the equations for x and y, so you'll only need to find the boundary for t. Can you find for which values of t your parametric equation gives you the points P and Q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already almost completed the problem. The only other question is what values of t should we use. The starting point is given as $(12,0)$, which corresponds to $t=0$ or $t=2\pi$ in your equation. The ending point is given as $(0,0)$, which corresponds to $t=\pi$ in your equation. Thus, if we restrict ourselves to $0<t<2\pi$, the answer could either be $0<t<\pi$ or $\pi<t<2\pi$, depending on if you want the top or bottom arc of the circle.

Comment: Thanks! After posting I thought about it a bit more and came to the same conclusion you did (with the help of the comments other people provided).